# How to accumulate total in tuple?

Tags: python

I have a tuple like this:

```
fruit_list_amount = [('16', 'Watermeloenen'), ('360', 'Watermeloenen'), ('6', 'Watermeloenen'), ('75', 'Watermeloenen'), ('9', 'Watermeloenen'), ('688', 'Appels'), ('22','Sinaasappels')]
```

And I try to return total for each label. So 16 + 360 + 6... for Watermeloenen

So I try it like this:

```
import locale
from locale import atof, setlocale, LC_NUMERIC
import itertools
import operator

def accumulate_first(l):
    locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = "."
    locale._override_localeconv["decimal_point"] = ","
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale='de_DE.UTF-8')
    it = itertools.groupby(l, operator.itemgetter(0))
    for key, subiter in it:
        yield key, sum(locale.atof(key[0]) for key in subiter)
```

But then the return value is:

```
[('16', 16.0), ('360', 360.0), ('6', 6.0), ('75', 75.0), ('9', 9.0), ('688', 688.0), ('22', 22.0)]
```

Question: how can I improve this?

Comment: Why not build a dictionary keyed on fruit name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a dictionary keyed on fruit name. You can then directly look up the total "count"

```
fruit_list_amount = [('16', 'Watermeloenen'), ('360', 'Watermeloenen'), ('6', 'Watermeloenen'), ('75', 'Watermeloenen'), ('9', 'Watermeloenen'), ('688', 'Appels'), ('22','Sinaasappels')] 

fruit_dict = {}

for n, f in fruit_list_amount:
    fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + int(n)

print(fruit_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Watermeloenen': 466, 'Appels': 688, 'Sinaasappels': 22}
```